# Does character level determine level of items crafted from legendary/set plans?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been collecting set and legendary Blacksmith plans as I level my characters, and I teach each of them to Haedrig as I find them. Recently, though, I've started to notice that only a few of these plans are used to make level 70 items, so I'm hesitant to keep collecting them unless I'm playing on a maxed character.

What I want to know is whether or not the level of my character at the time I obtain the plans will affect the level of the item(s) crafted from those plans. (If there are any differences in this regard between legendary and set plans, details would be appreciated.)

If character level *does* have some effect on what level the crafted item will be, is it possible to get another version of the plan later for a higher-level version of the same item, or am I stuck with the low-level version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Character level does **not** influence the level of dropped plans, it might influence what plans drop, but a plan for archon spaulders of strength is always going to be a level 60 item. This goes for all dropped recipes. If the resulting item is a Legendary, a set (basically a subclass from legendaries) or a rare doesn't matter.

The crafted items will also always be crafted at the same level regardless of what level the character crafting them is. A lvl 1 character can craft lvl 70 items.

Comment: OK, that's a huge relief. Thanks for the information. I think I read it somewhere else, but just to be clear: it is possible to get higher-level versions of those items if they're dropped rather than crafted, right? That is, if I used my level 70 character and found, say, a Demon Hand, would it drop as a level 70 item, or would it have the same level (~34 or so, if I recall) and similar stat ranges as the crafted item?

Comment: If it's a crafted legendary, I don't think you can find them as dropped items. But if they do drop, everything is set to your level.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, character level means nothing at all.  Each crafted item has a required level to be used, and it will roll from those affix pools at the time of creation.

You can generally tell around what level the plan will be, by checking the required blacksmith level.  A level 10 plan requires level 60, and level 12 plans require level 70.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I accepted the other answer already, but +1 for the details about the potential rolls and the tip about required blacksmith level.