# If you create the Hell Fire ring (the new one) with a level 1 monk, does i still roll level 70 stats?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Hell Fire ring does not have a level requirement. It also has a chance to roll Main stat.  Will there be any difference between making it with a level 1 monk, as opposed to a level 70 monk. Will the stats be the same? Meaning will they roll at their level 70 equivelant, as a higher stat?

Comment: According to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169592/does-character-level-determine-level-of-items-crafted-from-legendary-set-plans), it should not be affected and roll the proper stats for its level. I feel this is a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, that had nothing to do with the Hell Fire ring. I didn't ask about "Drops" or "plan drops"...I have the plan for the Hell Fire ring already. I also have all the mats for it. I ask does the character that CREATES it with the blacksmith matter...read the question again.

Comment: Read the first answer, it does state that the level of character does not matter. The second answer does also state the same.

Comment: No problem, the question is about legendary plans, which the hellfire ring falls under.