# Is it possible to un-learn crafting recipes?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've.. "accidentally" taught the blacksmith a recipe at level 23, and now it's useless at level 70. I've heard recipes don't drop after you've taught the blacksmith the item, so am I screwed now? Have I completely botched that Legendary for all my characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does character level determine level of items crafted from legendary/set plans?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169592/does-character-level-determine-level-of-items-crafted-from-legendary-set-plans)

Comment: The recipes have a fixed level that won't change.

Comment: The question does seem to be very similar, but it also appears to be an incomplete/incorrect answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to un-learn a recipe.  But luck is with you! Every legendary has a level 70 equivalent.  It'll be slightly renamed (ie. [Umbral Oath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/umbral-oath) has a level of 9, and it's level 70 variant is the Living [Umbral Oath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/living-umbral-oath)), but the sprite will be the same, and the stats it gives will be along the same lines, just modified for level 70.

So the level your character is at to teach the blacksmith is irrelevant.  The plan will teach the same thing, regardless, but you don't need to worry, as every plan has a level 70
equivalent.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't even tried that! I just assumed since the tooltip showed ilvl 23 that's what would pop out!

Comment: Waaaaiit a minute.. this doesn't seem to work. I've tried crafting "Wall of Bone" that I taught the blacksmith at lvl 23, and now at lvl 70 it still comes out lvl 23.

Comment: To you have any source to back this up? Cause from experience, crafting low level legendaries with my 70 monk always resulted in the legendary being its designed level, not 70. Like Cain's Fate set that is level 23.

Comment: You also contradict yourself here if you look at your answer [there](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169592/does-character-level-determine-level-of-items-crafted-from-legendary-set-plans).

Comment: this is not correct.  There are 2 sets of recipies.  The legacy set, which is low level, will never level up with you.  The new set won't drop until you are level 60+ and will be level 70 when crafted.

Comment: @z', can the second plans still drop if you've learned the legacy plans?

Comment: @Snailer yes they're completely different plans.  The legacy plans will actually stop dropping once you reach level 61 even if you haven't learned them, the only way to get them is to play at low levels.

Comment: Cool, you should post that as an answer and provide a source or I'll just accept it when it's proven in-game.

Comment: @z' Er?  That's not been my experience.  The Game Guide on Battle.net doesn't have duplicates of the recipes, and they're pretty good at making sure all instances of items are available.  It might be fully up to date, but if this works the way you say it does, there should be something there about it, and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: Oh, no, there we go.  There are basically reworded plans for level 70 versions of those items.  Weird; I was sure there was something about legendaries crafting at your level.  Wonder where I remembered that from?

Comment: @Snailer no need frank revised his answer and is now correct